# apache2: Perl lib version (5.28.1) doesn't match executable '/usr/sbin/apache2' version (5.20.2)

Tags: perl, debian, apache2

I have installed Debian 10 in order to migrate a web server from one machine to this Debian 10 machine. The web server built on apache2 needs mod_perl. The module was not found on the new machine, so I installed perl5.28 (and mod_perl.so has been added). But now it seems there is a mismatch between a previous perl version (5.20) and the latest one (5.28). I use the perl binary correspondint to v5.28, @INC contains directories related to v5.28 (according to "env -i perl -V"). But when I try to start the apache2 server, I get this error: "apache2: Perl lib version (5.28.1) doesn't match executable  '/usr/sbin/apache2' version (5.20.2)". Can anyone help? Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: perl isn't binary compatible between releases. If your module was built against perl version X, it can only be loaded by perl version X, not perl version Y. Why not just install the normal Debian packages, which should all be on the same page version-wise?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to uninstall perl5.28 (using dpkg -r) in order to (re)install perl5.20. But, surprisingly, the list of packages that were uninstalled did all refer to v5.20. Are you suggesting installation of perl-modules_5.20? When I try this, an error message says that there is a conflict with perl5.28.

Comment: It looks like Debian 10/buster uses perl 5.28. The libapache2-mod-perl package depends on that version, at least...

Comment: welcome to [so], a programmer's forum. For server-maintenance questions, you should head over to [sf].

Comment: Ok. So I restarted from scratch. I reinstalled Debian 10, configured apache2, set the /var/www files, and so on. Now I can see that perl5.28 is indeed already installed (from genuine Debian), not by myself. When starting the apache2 server, I have the following error: "Invalid command 'PerRequire'". This indicates, according to me, that the perl module mod_perl.so is not found. And, indeed, it is not present in /usr/lib/apache2/modules. How can I build this module? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When you built apache with mod_perl, you used v5.20, but it seems that's not around anymore. Different versions of Perl are not guaranteed (or even attempt to be) binary compatible. Between Perl versions, you'll likely have to re-compile all XS modules, too.

You need to recompile apache with the Perl that you want to use, or install the Perl that apache wants to use. This time you may want to statically compile mod_perl into apache.

This problem isn't specific to Perl, though. Many software libraries will complain similarly when you replace the library they compiled against.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How may I recompile apache?